# Crystal reports Hide Details section on first page, but showing report header and page footer

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I'm new to crystal reports.

I would like to show the report header and the page footer on the first page of the report, but not the details section.

Similar questions to suppress details section on the first page can be found on stackoverflow, but the usual anwser is to check "New page after" in the section expert of the report header. But when I do this the page footer is also not shown on the first page (which I would like to show).

Also, a conditional suppress of the detail section with "PageNumber=1;" does not seem to work. In this case, crystal does not show the detail section at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not sure what you're doing, but it sounds like you need two details sections, one for the first page that's empty, and one for every other page that contains whatever you want to print.  You can suppress the detail section with contents if `pagenumber = 1`

Comment: Many thx. Your suggestions worked. 
"not sure what you're doing" - I want to generate a billing tool. on the first page is like the standard information and a summary (all in the report header). in the page footer is some details of the billing company. and on the following pages are supposed to be the billing details...

Comment: Done (since I am also new to stackoverflow, the upvote is not publicly displayed but I have done also that.)
Thx again